# Listener does not work for back stack of fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have listener for back stack:

```
    getFragmentManager().
    addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Change fragment");
        }

    });
```

And two buttons. Event onClick for first button:

```
            getFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().
            add(R.id.root, fragm).
            commit();
```

Event onClick for second button:

```
            getFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().
            remove(fragm).commit();
```

But the listener does not work. Function onBackStackChanged does not call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At a guess because the first transaction hasn't been added to the backstack via a call to `addToBackStack(...)`. So try:

```
        getFragmentManager().
        beginTransaction().
        add(R.id.root, fragm).
        addToBackStack(null).
        commit();
```